Adding controls dynamically to a DevExpress Layout Group Control doesn't maintain control size and preferred location
I am trying to add a user control when a user clicks a button. I need to be able to add multiple of these user controls. The problem is that the first user control adds great, but subsequent ones are small and are added to the bottom instead of right under the first one. I have tried manipulating the size and location, but with no success. I currently have a DevExpress LayoutGroupControl that I use to contain all of my user controls. The code I use to add the user control is as follows:
private void sbActionRequirement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ctrlRequirements requirements = new ctrlRequirements(dimensionBindingSource, requirementConditionBindingSource)    

   LayoutControlItem item = lcgActionRequirements.AddItem("New Requirement", requirements);
   item.TextVisible = false;

   lcgActionRequirements.Add(item);
}

This is what it looks like with two of the controls added with the second one being at the bottom and cut off. How do I dynamically add several controls to the same Layout Group Control and it look correct?


Add border to the UC to see if there are any additional space.

You may need to use the Move method to position the newly-created LayoutControlItem. See: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2252/controls-and-libraries/form-layout-managers/layout-and-data-layout-controls/examples/how-to-create-layout-groups-and-items-in-code
